# Rails model joined has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, model-associations

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
class Cashflow < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to from_account, :class_name => 'Account'
    belongs_to to_account, :class_name => 'Account'
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :cashflows
end
```

where `Account::cashflows` is obviously a list of all `cashflows` that either have the `account_id` stored in `from_account` or in `to_account`.

I'm confused. What is the proper way of handling such a case? How bad design is this? What would be the proper way of designing such a relation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the right structure as there can only two accounts be involved in a particular transaction/cashflow. if you use many to many association you would need to handle the validation for not involving more or less than 2 accounts. For your current structure you can change your moidel associations to be:

```
class Cashflow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to from_account, :class_name => 'Account', :foreign_key => :from_account
  belongs_to to_account, :class_name => 'Account', :foreign_key => :to_account
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :debits, :class_name => 'Cashflow', :foreign_key => :from_account
  has_many :credits, :class_name => 'Cashflow', :foreign_key => :to_account

  def cashflows
    transactions = []
    transactions << self.debits
    transactions << self.credits
    transactions.flatten!

    ## or may be the following commented way
    # Cashflow.where('from_account = ? OR to_account = ?', self.id, self.id)
  end
end
```

This way you can keep track of the amount debited/credited in a particular account and also get the accounts involved in a particular transaction/cashflow.

Comment: Sounds right. Now, I have tons of objects which need to do `account.cashflows`. I guess I can use a scope for this. What would you advise?

Comment: Also the side question would be: how do you get a list of SIGNED cashflows. like `account.cashflows` with cashflows having signed value for the given account?! That's an tricky question. :/

Comment: If you create an association then it would look for the `account_id` in `cashflows` table. And if you create a scope then you cannot use it on model instance so you would need to create a method `cashflows`. And what do you mean by SIGNED cashflows?

Comment: I have added the `cashflows` method in my answer.

Comment: Signed cashflow means that when you do `f = account.cashflows.first.amount`, you can get `+amount` or `-amount` depending on whether the account was linked to the cashflow through the `from_account` or the `to_account` reference.

Comment: About scope versus method. You can do both by creating a scope and calling it from inside a method. So you can access it whatever you need and still have 1 line. You just need to have two names though.

Answer (score 2):

Suggestions on top of my mind

1) Your class (table) `cashflows` should have two columns from_account and to_account.

2) `from_account` and `to_account` should have the id of the account concerned

3) `cashflows` should `belongs_to :account`

4) `account` should `has_many :cashflows`. Ideally it should be `cash_flows`

These should be good starting points. Don't they meet your requirements?

Comment: Yes sir! Except 4 but I don't think the naming convention impacts here.

Comment: @Arindam model class is `Cashflow` not `CashFlow` so the association name is correct.

Comment: Right. missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use has and belongs to many association here:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :incoming_cashflows, :class_name => 'Cashflow', :join_table => :incoming_cashflows_accounts
  has_and_belongs_to_many :outcoming_cashflows, :class_name => 'Cashflow', :join_table => :outcoming_cashflows_accounts
end

class Cashflow < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :from_accounts, :class_name => 'Account', :join_table => :incoming_cashflows_accounts
  has_and_belongs_to_many :to_accounts, :class_name => 'Account', :join_table => :outcoming_cashflows_accounts
end
```

Also you will need some validation code allows to add only one account to Cashflow.

Comment: That's what I first thought of doing. Now the trouble of your solution is that you can't distinguish the direction of the cashflow. Cashflow has a :amount field which carries a value which applies negatively on from_account and positively on to_account. Any idea?

Comment: I think you can solve this problem easily - add method like get_direction, which will return result based on :from_accounts and :to_accounts items count. On incoming cashflow to_accounts.count will be always 0, on outcoming - from_accounts.count will be always 0.